# Editing submitted data from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have a page I am creating where administrators can edit data from a previous form using checkboxes. I have already managed to display the data already submitted using checkboxes using the following code as I have it submitted into paragraphs on the previous page:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var str = document.getElementById('size').innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace(/<p>/g,'<input type="checkbox" value="');
var res = res.replace(/<\/p>/g,'" id="size" name="size[]" checked />');
document.getElementById('size').innerHTML=res;
});
</script>
```

But am unsure how to go about displaying the remaining fields, I assume I would somehow need to implement a a for loop but I am unsure the best way to go about doing this.

The content is currently being stored into the database as follows:

```
<p>xs</p><p>s</p><p>m</p><p>l</p><p>xl</p>
```

Many thanks!

Costa

Comment: Just wanted to make a small suggestion. If you are using jQuery, try to get your elements using the following syntax: `$("#size")` instead of using the `document.getElementById('size')` function that is built into the browser. You can also leverage the `html()` jQuery function to get get your inner HTML content: `$("#size").html()`

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this. Why store content in a database as `<p>` tags and then use JavaScript to parse it? Why not just serialize an array into the database and let PHP parse it?

Comment: On a different page I am separating the code using radio buttons and commas on another. It just seemed the most logical approach to me. I'm still fairly new to PHP so there may be better methods I have overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you could do this:

```
$("p").each(function(index) {
    $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" id="size" name="size[]" checked> ' +     $(this).text() + ' </input>');
});
```

This will iterate over all the p elements and replace them with input types for whatever p elements present on the page.

**EDIT**

If you can set the value attribute from the previous form then something like this might work assuming that this might come back from the DB:

```
<p class="paragraph" >xs</p>
<p class="paragraph" value="24">s</p>
<p class="paragraph" >m</p>
<p class="paragraph" value="34">l</p>
<p class="paragraph" value="36">xl</p>
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
$("p").each(function (index) {
    if ($(this).attr("value") !== undefined) {
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" id="size" name="size[]" checked> ' + $(this).text() + ' </input>');
    } else {   
        $(this).replaceWith('<input type="checkbox" id="size" name="size[]" unchecked>' + $(this).text() + ' </input>');
    }
});
```

Here is aanother [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/janarde/ny6xD/) demonstrating this. This assumes you've already retrieved the data from the DB.

Comment: Thanks for the help but not quite, let's say only half the checkboxes are being pulled from the database, I need the rest to show up unchecked.